# Johansen Test gave me cointegration relationships for stationary series

Tags: time-series, forecasting, stationarity, cointegration

I want to build a VAR model for 7 series. All the series are stationary, but when I ran the Johansen cointegration test, it said that I have cointegration in my series.

Does it make sense to have cointegration for stationary series?

Comment: By definition, no, you can't have cointegration between stationary series. So, why did you run the test?

Comment: How did the test results look like? Is it possible that you misinterpreted them? Did you go row by row in the output table and rejected all possible cointegration ranks above zero?

Comment: I rejected the null hypothesis that there is no cointegration relationship for every r, the value of the test was way higher than the 1%,5% or 10% value.

Comment: This is precisely what you should get when the series are stationary. This is actually an indication that the series are stationary, as every possible linear combination is found to be stationary by the Johansen test. Which means you have originally misinterpreted the test result, but the result itself might very well be valid and is intuitive.